# why does't my title center when I use margin: 0 auto?

Tags: css

I have set the div to inline-block and set the margin to (0 auto). Why doesn't it work?
[image]

Comment: or you know provide your markup instead of a random screenshot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-another-div)

Comment: It's not working because margin: o auto will affect divs/blocks with display: block and defined width, like here:  https://codepen.io/TunderScripts/pen/ayYjXX

Comment: Because it is an `inline-block` element, which means it obeys the `inline` properties (you cannot assign left/right auto margins to inline elements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. An **inline** block lays out its content like a block, but is laid out inline in its parent and you can have text before and after on the same line, so auto-margins don't do any kind of centering, just like they would not on a span. You need to be `display: block` for automargins to center things

2.a. If you had `display: block` it still wouldn't work, as by default they fill the whole width. auto margins center things by equaly distributing leftover space to both side, but you need to have leftover space to begin with. try using the `width` or `max-width` properties. If you do not have a fixed width, and want something that depends on the size of the content, try `width: fit-content` / `width: -moz-fit-content` / `width: -webkit-fit-content` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#fit-content).

2.b. Alternatively, depending on exactly what you're after, instead of centering the div in its parent, you may want to center the text inside the div, with `text-align: center`. You'll still need to make the div a block rather than an inline block, otherwise its width will be that of the text it contains, and there won't be any centering possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `text-align: center;` to center elements with text. Divs actually have 100% width, so they cannot be centered unless you set them width property.

Comment: While by default a `div` is indeed a block-level element, the OP clearly states that the element is set with `display: inline-block`, so it's actually not expanding to 100%. Though in this case, the OP can set `text-align: center` on the _parent_ `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help :)

```css
.title {text-align:center;}
```

```html
<div class="title">Me Center</div>
```